# Items are not getting wrapped on adding more items with flex-wrap property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I want the items added to wrap around and get added to next row and not scroll to right side.

The items wrap to next row if I do not use button to add list items and just add items manually to `li`. I have used the `flex-wrap: wrap` property of `flex-box`.

```js
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
    $('#ticketsDemosss').append($('<li  class="flex-item">').text('sds'));
});
```

```css
.flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row; /* Safari */
    flex-direction:  row;
    flex-wrap:  wrap;
}
.flex-item {
    background: tomato;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    line-height: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
}
ul li{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl id="viewbranchcontact-2">
<ul id="ticketsDemosss" class="flex-container">
<!-- add LI here -->
</ul>
</dl>

<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: If you want to `wrap` element to new line, use `inline-block` instead.

Comment: You forgot to add `display: flex` on container `ul`.

Comment: Thanks a lot i got this one. Another help. What do i do to make the button appear on the last element and not at the bottom. For example another element is added when i click the last element. Sorry i am really new to using CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the elements are inline and there is no space between the elements, so it's treated like a long word. You can either...

- apply `word-break: break-all` to the parent
- make the li's `inline-block` instead (what I did below)
- put spaces between the elements

```js
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
    $('#ticketsDemosss').append($('<li  class="flex-item">').text('sds'));
});
```

```css
.flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row; /* Safari */
    flex-direction:  row;
    flex-wrap:  wrap;
}
.flex-item {
    background: tomato;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    line-height: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul li{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl id="viewbranchcontact-2">
<ul id="ticketsDemosss" class="flex-container">
<!-- add LI here -->
</ul>
</dl>

<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Another help. What do i do to make the button appear on the last element and not at the bottom. For example another element is added when i click the last element. Sorry i am really new to using CSS

Comment: @darsh you're welcome. you should try to figure it out on your own or make another post, it's too involved for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `display: inline-flex; box-sizing: border-box;` .in `flex-item` class

```js
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
    $('#ticketsDemosss').append($('<li  class="flex-item">').text('sds'));
});
```

```css
.flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row; /* Safari */
    flex-direction:  row;
    flex-wrap:  wrap;   
}
.flex-item {
    background: tomato;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    line-height: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    
    display: inline-flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul li{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl id="viewbranchcontact-2">
<ul id="ticketsDemosss" class="flex-container">
<!-- add LI here -->
</ul>
</dl>

<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: This worked too. Thanks a lot. Another help. What do i do to make the button appear on the last element and not at the bottom. For example another element is added when i click the last element. Sorry i am really new to using CSS